# My Java method is not working with JavaMail variables as arguments

Tags: java, string, variables, jakarta-mail

I'm creating a program in Java to alert a user if they get an email about a password reset. I have sent an email to myself with the text "Your password has been reset" and created a method that analyzes the email:

```
    private static boolean passwordResetFinder(String email) {
    boolean passReset = false;

    if (email.matches(".*password.*") && (email.matches(".*changed.*") || email.matches(".*reset.*"))) {
        passReset = true;
    }
```

and I call the method like this:

```
String email = new String();
...
open connection to inbox using JavaMail
...

Object content = emailReader.getContent();
email = content.toString();

if(passwordResetFinder(email)) {
   System.out.println("Password Alert");
}
```

And this doesn't work. However if I put the following:

```
if (passwordResetFinder("Your password has been reset")
```

or

```
email = content.toString();    
email = "Your password has been reset";    
    if(passwordResetFinder(email))
```

it works. Why is this?

Comment: Probably because you're checking for `password` and passing in `Password` - it's case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the toString() of the Object returned by emailReader.getContent() does not give you a String-representation of the text the mail contains. This might be the case if it is a subclass of Multipart when reading 
multipart mails or a Stream if the type of the message is unkown.

> Return the content as a Java object. The type of the returned object is of course dependent on the content itself. For example, the object returned for "text/plain" content is usually a String object. The object returned for a "multipart" content is always a Multipart subclass. For content-types that are unknown to the DataHandler system, an input stream is returned as the content
>
> https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Part.html#getContent%28%29